# Baofeng UV-5R: Severe static/interference on UHF frequencies

Tags: rfi, uhf, baofeng, uv-5r

I have a U5-5R, which I've set up to use (among other things) the analog (NFM) frequencies of the PMR446-band. I've been using it with the stock (136-174/400-520MHz) antenna and a monophone connected using the Kenwood-connector. I'm experiencing some pretty severe static/interference using those bands. I'll add that I'm experiencing said static/interference also when I disconnect the monophone. Short video example [here](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/UGVu25RaKgM).

I've set squelch to the highest level, which didn't help. Other radios (PMR446-dedicated units) did not experience these issues.

I have been using the radio extensively in the VHF-band, and have not experienced any issues there.

Answer (score 1):

this is not horribly surprising

these units have notoriously awful front end filtering for their intended use (the ham bands).

you didn't really ask a question, but I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Baofeng radios are known for having a wide front end, i.e. very low selectivity. This means they’re not able to to concentrate very well on a specific frequency, and instead bring in artefacts of adjacent signals. As far as I know there’s no way to fix this.